# Specifying the type of a templated type with a templated type

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, vector

What happens when I want to define the template type of my vector with a templated type? I have a class Customer which is templated so that the constructor can take an argument of type `vector<T>`. Now I want to instantiate a global Vector of type Customer and find myself wanting to type `vector<Customer<Customer<Customer<etc<etc>>>>>`  .

I know this is probably a noobish question but I would love to get a good concise explanation of this little pickle i find my self in.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `vector` of a specific type of `Customer` then everything is simple:

```
template < typename T >
class Customer
{
public:
  Customer( std::vector< Customer< T > > vec );
}

std::vector< Customer<CustomerType> > v;
```

or

```
std::vector< Customer<CustomerType>* > v;
```

However, if you want **different** instances of the Customer template, then there's no other way than to define some common base for the classes, and store it instead:

```
class CustomerBase 
{ 
   /* common functionality */
};

template < typename T > 
class Customer : public CustomerBase
{
}

std::vector< CustomerBase* > v;
v.push_back( Customer< TypeA >() );
v.push_back( Customer< TypeB >() );
```

Comment: I realised that my confusion stemed from the templated type that I needed to specify as my type for customer neededing its templated type to be specified as Customer... Doh! Thanks for the swift response!